# Ubuntu Server boot gets stuck after xen install

Tags: ubuntu, server, xen

So I'm trying to set up Ubuntu server 18.0.4LTS with Xen hypervisor. My problem is 
that as when I install Xen and try to reboot, the boot sequence hangs on the line.

```
[OK] Initializing AppArmour
```

It doesn't give me any sort of error, it just stays on that line and the little cursor in the bottom corner stops flashing.

I'm following the steps in this tutorial
https://wiki.xenproject.org/wiki/Xen_Project_Beginners_Guide

I was able to get xen installed yesterday without this problem using the exact same steps on the exact same machine.

I can take a brand new install of Ubuntu server, and type the following 2 commands:

```
sudo apt-get install xen-hypervisor-amd64
sudo reboot
```

And the server won't boot up. If anyone has any insight into this I'd greatly appreciate it because this issue has me tearing my hair out.